# How do I implement hide TabController in swift?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I'm using the library https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar

I had trying to hide the tab controller only.

Anyone helping me?

This library default set hiding the navigation bar.

Comment: There is no tab bar controller in the example. Do you mean tab bar?

Comment: Yeah I mean tab bar.. This library is support hiding the tab bar with navigation bar. But I want implement hiding the tab bar only not navigation bar.

Comment: So look for the part of the code that hides the navigation bar and don't do that part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying now and When I solved then I will update my question thanks :)